# How can I properly use a flag controlled loop so that a specific task is performed only once?

Tags: c++, loops, boolean, flags

I am making a program that asks the user for two rational numbers and depending on whether the user chooses to add or subtract, my program will perform the task and then have to option to continue adding or subtracting or exiting.

So far I have most of my coding done, but am having a problem with writing a flag controlled loop. For my program, a show menu will appear that will ask the user whether they want to subtract, add or quit.

If the user chooses to add, the screen will clear and a title should appear at the top that says "Addition of rational numbers". This title should only appear once, and after this my program will ask the user to enter a rational number.

Since the program is supposed to add two rational numbers, after the user inputs the first rational number my program will ask the user for another rational number.

So in total, my program will ask the question two times.

Question:
The problem that I am having is that once the title "Addition of rational numbers" appears and my program asks the user for the number the second time, the title will come out again. I tried using a flag controlled loop, but no matter what I tried it will either skip the title or repeat it every time the question is asked. Below is the code that I am referring to:

```
void GetRational(char state, int& num, int& den)
{
    char c;
    bool once;
    once = true;

    while (once)
    {
        if (state == 'A' || state == 'a')
        {
            cout << "Addition of rational numbers" << endl;
            once = false;
        }
        else if (state == 'S' || state == 's')
        {
            cout << "Subtraction of rational numbers" << endl;
            once = true;
        }
        else break;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a fraction (n/d): ";
        cin >> num >> c >> den;
        if (den == 0)
            cout << "\nDenominator must not be 0";
        else break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a loop for something that should happen only once???

Comment: You should put title out of this function. This function seems like a input check, not for title.

Comment: This is an XY problem, you're trapped yourself in a loop you created. Think out of the loop. If `GetRational` is called twice, then you shouldn't put `state == 'A' ` part in this function. Since it just need once.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner so a lot of these concepts are new to me, but the reason I tried using a flag controlled loop for the title is that I wanted to get it to show up only once. Initially I had only used the if statements, but the title keeps repeating every time my program ask the user to enter a fraction so I thought if I used a flag control I could make it show up only once if that makes sense.

Comment: Try moving `bool once` out of the function and make it global. It might be the case that you are calling the function `GetRational(...)` multiple times.

Comment: Ohh ok, I see what you mean thanks! Let me go ahead and try that.

Comment: I put the coding for the title in another of my functions and it worked! Thank you so much! I've been working on this program for a while, so it got to the point that I couldn't see the errors I was making.

Comment: *"Initially I had only used the if statements, but [there was a problem] so I used [Y]." Then Y produced the same problem as you had before so you asked how to fix Y instead of going back to your original problem.* -- that follows the definition of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) remarkably well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `bool once` outside of the function `GetRational(...)`, it may be the case that you are calling `GetRational(...)` multiple times and each time `bool once` might be getting reinitialized. So the snippet would look like this:

```
bool once = true;
void GetRational(char state, int& num, int& den)
{
    char c;

    while (once)
    {
        if (state == 'A' || state == 'a')
        {
            cout << "Addition of rational numbers" << endl;
            once = false;
        }
        else if (state == 'S' || state == 's')
        {
            cout << "Subtraction of rational numbers" << endl;
            once = true;
        }
        else break;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a fraction (n/d): ";
        cin >> num >> c >> den;
        if (den == 0)
            cout << "\nDenominator must not be 0";
        else break;
    }
}
```

---

As Davislor pointed out in the comments:

> The problem with globals, especially globals that aren’t constants, is
>   that any part of the program can mess around with them. That makes it
>   very hard to track down which line of your program is causing a bug.
>   It’s less of an issue if you split your program into modules and you
>   can at least guarantee that only that one file could have mucked it
>   up.

So, another option would be to use `once` as a static variable **if** you don't want to use a global variable.

> Static variables when used inside function are initialized only once,
>   and then they hold their value even through function calls.

With static variable, the code snippet would look like this:

```
void GetRational(char state, int& num, int& den)
{
    // will only be initialized one, at the first time call of function GetRational(...)
    static bool once = true; 
    char c;

    while (once)
    {
        if (state == 'A' || state == 'a')
        {
            cout << "Addition of rational numbers" << endl;
            once = false;
        }
        else if (state == 'S' || state == 's')
        {
            cout << "Subtraction of rational numbers" << endl;
            once = true;
        }
        else break;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a fraction (n/d): ";
        cin >> num >> c >> den;
        if (den == 0)
            cout << "\nDenominator must not be 0";
        else break;
    }
}
```

Read more about `static` keyword: [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/)

Comment: I moved bool once out of the GetRational function and was able to fix the problem I was having! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to know it helped!

Comment: This makes `once` a global variable. Most coders recommend you use those as little as possible, so you might find yourself getting some comments in red pen from your TA.

Comment: The problem with globals, especially globals that aren’t constants, is that any part of the program can mess around with them. That makes it very hard to track down which line of your program is causing a bug. It’s less of an issue if you split your program into modules and you can at least guarantee that only that one file could have mucked it up.

Comment: Updated the answer as per suggestions @Davislor Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To make `GetRational` remember the value of `once` the next time you invoke it, declare the variable as

```
static bool once = true;
```

The `static` variable will only be initiailized one time, which will be before the first call to `GetRational`.

Then, after you check it and before you return from `GetRational`, set

```
once = false;
```

This will persist between calls to `GetRational`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Use if loop.

```
bool once="true";
     void GetRational(char state, int& num, int& den)
        {
            char c;


                if(once=="true")
               { 
                if (state == 'A' || state == 'a')
                {
                    cout << "Addition of rational numbers" << endl;
                }
                else if (state == 'S' || state == 's')
                {
                    cout << "Subtraction of rational numbers" << endl;

                }
                else { }
          }

            while (1)
            {   
                once="false";
                cout << "\nPlease enter a fraction (n/d): ";
                cin >> num >> c >> den;
                if (den == 0) 
                    cout << "\nDenominator must not be 0";
                else break;
            }
        }
```